# Django ModelFormSet object changes type on post

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I'm converting a page from using manually rendered post/get functions to one using class-based views. I am attempting to move towards using all of Django's built-in functionality. But I'm encountering a confusing error where the ModelFormSet object is not the right type when the form is posted.

I have this form:

```
class AssignmentDatesForm(forms.ModelForm): 

class Meta:
    model = AssignmentDates
    fields = [
    'assignment_name',
    'start_date',
    'due_date',
    'end_date',
    ]

    widgets = { 'start_date' : forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs ={ 'class' : 'datepicker'}),
                'due_date' : forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs ={ 'class' : 'datepicker' }),
                'end_date' : forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs ={ 'class' : 'datepicker' }),}

def clean(self):
    logging.warning("Clean function")
    logging.warning("start_date: " + str(start_date))
    logging.warning("due_date: " + str(due_date))
    logging.warning("end_date: " + str(end_date))
    # Actual validation logic here
```

And create the ModelFormSet using modelformset_factory:

```
AssignmentDatesFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(
model = AssignmentDates,
form = AssignmentDatesForm,
extra = 0,
)
```

Here is the view, shortened for brevity:

```
class EditDueDates(CurrentUserMixin, ModelFormSetView):
model = AssignmentDates
page_title = 'Edit Due Dates'

success_message = "Dates updated successfully!"
add_button_title = "Add Button Title"
form = AssignmentDatesForm
formset = AssignmentDatesFormSet
template_name = "edit_due_dates.html"
sidebar_group = ['scaffold', 'edit_due_dates']

columns = [
    ('Assignment Name', 'assignment_name'),
    ('Start Date', 'start_date'),
    ('Due Date', 'due_date'),
    ('End Date', 'end_date'),
    ]

fields = [
'assignment_name',
'start_date',
'due_date',
'end_date',
]

show_context_menu = False

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(EditDueDates, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # Date retrieval/ DB storage logic here

    form = AssignmentDatesFormSet(queryset = AssignmentDates.objects.filter(created_by = creds.get_OUNetID()))
    logging.warning("get_context_data form type: " + str(type(form)))
    context['form'] = form
    return context

def formset_valid(self, formset):
    logging.warning("formset_valid form type: " + str(type(formset)))
    cleaned_data = formset.clean()
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()            
    return super(EditDueDates, self).formset_valid(formset)
```

The ModelFormSet is displayed fine in the template, and the logging message I have above prints out the type of the form as:

```
 <class 'scaffold.forms.AssignmentDatesFormSet'>
```

But my clean function is never executed. When it executes the formset_valid function I have in the view and print out the formset type, I get this:

```
<class 'django.forms.formsets.AssignmentDatesFormFormSet'>
```

So it never executes my clean function because the type isn't right. Executing formset.clean() again just executes the clean function of this weird type.

I haven't a clue why it's a different type when it's POSTed from the template. If anyone has any ideas please let me know! Thank you!

-Will

Comment: What is ModelFormSetView?

Comment: It is a part of the extra-views in https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views. I didn't realize it wasn't a normal django view but an extension my apologies. I didn't think it did much more than a FormView. But now that you mention it it does give me an idea to go back to a basic view and see if the type comes back as expected.